# How do I compose format=flowed emails that include hanging indents with vim?

Tags: email, vim, formatting

Is there a good way to configure vim to send format=flowed emails that include hanging indents?

My complete vimrc (for testing purposes) is:

```
set nocompatible
set fo+=awn 
set tw=72
set ai
```

I'm typing something like:

```
 1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam 
    posuere dui lorem, et condimentum nulla. Sed pharetra justo nec ante 
    fringilla non mattis nisi blandit. Donec molestie ligula dolor. 
    Nulla facilisi. Aliquam vel nulla elit, mollis facilisis metus. Sed 
    id eros a ante blandit convallis id sit amet elit. Duis malesuada 
    lobortis leo a placerat. Sed ut ipsum nisl. Sed pretium mauris vitae 
    velit sollicitudin iaculis.
```

vim adds a trailing space to each line except the last, per set fo+=w. It also adds spaces for the hanging indent. It looks great!

My mail client sets the format=flowed header. The result when this email is viewed in either Mail.app or mutt is not pretty:

```
1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam     posuere dui lorem, et condimentum nulla. Sed pharetra justo nec ante     fringilla non mattis nisi blandit. Donec molestie ligula dolor.     Nulla facilisi. Aliquam vel nulla elit, mollis facilisis metus. Sed     id eros a ante blandit convallis id sit amet elit. Duis malesuada     lobortis leo a placerat. Sed ut ipsum nisl. Sed pretium mauris vitae     velit sollicitudin iaculis.
```

The paragraph wraps correctly, in the sense that resizing the reader client reflows it (which is not what you'll see here on stackoverflow, but you get the idea). The problem is, there are 5 spaces between "Etiam" and "posuere" and all the other lines that have been joined back together.

Is there a fix for this in vim? Or is this a limitation of the format=flowed spec? How do other people handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The paragraph wraps correctly, in the sense that resizing the reader client reflows it (which is not what you'll see here on stackoverflow, but you get the idea). The problem is, there are 5 spaces between "Etiam" and "posuere" and all the other lines that have been joined back together.

This is a limitation of the "format=flowed" MIME parameter as specified in [RFC 3676](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3676).  There is nothing in the specification that would allow a client to recognize the leading spaces as ornaments intended only for plaintext versions of the mail.

Section 4.1 of the RFC states:

> If the first character of a line is a space, the line has been space-stuffed (see Section 4.4).  Logically, this leading space is deleted before examining the line further (that is, before checking for flowed).

The referenced "space-stuffing" from Section 4.4:

> Space-stuffing adds a single space to the start of any line which needs protection when the message is generated.  On reception, if the first character of a line is a space, it is logically deleted.  This occurs after the test for a quoted line (which logically counts and deletes any quote marks), and before the test for a flowed line.

So an RFC 3676-compliant mail client would remove a single leading space from each line beginning with such a character and then (optionally) remove any the linebreaks that following a single space character.  This process would not touch the remaining leading whitespace